# Incorporating a Spanish Accent in a Word to be Displayed in Bold

Tags: bold, accents, spanish, boldmath

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}
\oddsidemargin -15pt \evensidemargin -15pt \topmargin -25pt
\headheight -5pt \headsep 0pt \textheight 9.95in \textwidth 6.25in
\parskip 10pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ARed}{RGB}{144,16,45}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge

\begin{bfseries}
{\textcolor{ARed}{\textit{Espa{${\tilde{n}}$}oles}}}
%\vskip 10pt
%{\textcolor{ARed}{\textit{Espa{\boldsymbol{${\tilde{n}}$}}oles}}}
\end{bfseries}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The hope was that the accented *n* would be be displayed in bold and with proper spacing between it and the following letter, *o*.

However, using

```
{\textcolor{ARed}{\textit{Espa{\boldsymbol{${\tilde{n}}$}}oles}}}
```

produces an error.

QUESTION: How may I, as simply as possible, properly accent the Spanish word *Espanoles* so that the word appears in bold with all the letters appropriately spaced?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you not able to type `ñ` directly from keyboard? Are you using a keyboard with English layout? Anyway, you can type it with `\~n`. No math mode needed.

Comment: don't use math mode to typeset text. That is conceptually wrong.

Comment: @egreg I got an error when I tried to use `\tilde` without it.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I previously couldn't get `n tilde` to be produced without using math mode. Sigur offered a suggestion which I hope to try shortly. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you for the `\~n` suggestion; it works nicely. If you wish, please post it as an answer so that I may upvote it and accept it.

Comment: @egreg I have tried Sigur's suggestion which works quite nicely. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: See [`texdoc comprehensive`](https://texdoc.org/serve/comprehensive/0), table 18

Comment: Many thanks @egreg for the very useful link.